# Have Two Adjacent Nav Sub-Menu Blocks

Tags: html, css, list, flexbox

I have a nav menu item that when hovered over brings up 6 sub menu items. I would like them to appear in two blocks of 3 adjacent to each other.

I would have thought the just doing `display: flex` on the parent element `.menu-item-1` would do this but it doesn't seem to be working?

I have to use `li` elements, but any assistance as to why it isn't working would be wonderful.

The current menu has the two blocks of 3 sub menu items sitting on top of each other so it only looks like three items.

codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/LwPvbq

```css
li {list-style-type: none}
  
ul.nav-menu-items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
  
.menu-item {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2rem 1rem 2rem 1rem
}

.menu-item-1 {
  display: flex;
}

/* SUB MENU */

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 1rem;
  top: 5rem;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 22rem;
}

.submenu-item {
  padding-bottom: .5rem;
}

.submenu-item:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.menu-item:hover .submenu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-menu-items">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-1">MENU-ITEM
        <ul class="submenu pratice-areas-submenu-1">
            <li class="submenu-item submenu-item-1"><a href="./" class="navigation--link">SUB MENU ITEM</a></li>
            <li class="submenu-item submenu-item-3"><a href="./" class="navigation--link">SUB MENU ITEM</a></li>
            <li class="submenu-item submenu-item-5"><a href="./" class="navigation--link">SUB MENU ITEM</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="submenu pratice-areas-submenu-2">
            <li class="submenu-item submenu-item-1"><a href="./" class="navigation--link">SUB MENU ITEM</a></li>
            <li class="submenu-item submenu-item-3"><a href="./" class="navigation--link">SUB MENU ITEM</a></li>
            <li class="submenu-item submenu-item-5"><a href="./" class="navigation--link">SUB MENU ITEM</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `position: absolute;` on `.submenu` is causing the items `.pratice-areas-submenu-1` to hide behind `.pratice-areas-submenu-2`. One naive way you can start fixing this by applying `left: 150%;` to `.pratice-areas-submenu-2`.

Another way is to remove `position: absolute` on `.submenu` and add to it `margin-top: 2rem; transform: translate(-6rem);`. There are so many other ways too.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for the reason of it not working described by @waleed Iqbal.

My personal way of solving this would be to insert a submenu-container and position it as absolute and make it display flex.

```css
li {list-style-type: none}
  
ul.nav-menu-items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
  
.menu-item {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2rem 1rem 2rem 1rem
}

.menu-item-1 {
 // display: flex;
}

/* SUB MENU */

.submenu-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5rem;
  display: flex;
}
.submenu {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 1rem;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 22rem;
}

.submenu-item {
  padding-bottom: .5rem;
}

.submenu-item:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.menu-item:hover .submenu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-menu-items">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-1">MENU-ITEM
      <div class="submenu-container">
        <ul class="submenu pratice-areas-submenu-1">
            <li class="submenu-item submenu-item-1"><a href="./" class="navigation--link">SUB MENU ITEM</a></li>
            <li class="submenu-item submenu-item-3"><a href="./" class="navigation--link">SUB MENU ITEM</a></li>
            <li class="submenu-item submenu-item-5"><a href="./" class="navigation--link">SUB MENU ITEM</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="submenu pratice-areas-submenu-2">
            <li class="submenu-item submenu-item-1"><a href="./" class="navigation--link">SUB MENU ITEM</a></li>
            <li class="submenu-item submenu-item-3"><a href="./" class="navigation--link">SUB MENU ITEM</a></li>
            <li class="submenu-item submenu-item-5"><a href="./" class="navigation--link">SUB MENU ITEM</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zgxWgw).